# Open Source Interactive Map

Tags: dictionary, mapping, interactive

Looking for an open source mapping tool.

I need to create an interactive map that'd I'd be able to highlight certain highways, buildings, and areas. The map would have to allow visitors to navigate around the area and click any of the highlighted objects for more information to appear.

I'm guessing something like this might be possible with google maps, I just didn't know if there's a better or easier tool I could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like it will end up working - http://www.gethifi.com/blog/a-jquery-plugin-for-zoomable-interactive-maps